# How can I plot a categorical vs categorical plot?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, seaborn, categorical-data

I want to check the count of categories (in the first column) with the count of categories in the second column. I have two columns:
1. Max_glu_serum with categories: None, Norm, <200, <300.
2. Readmitted with categories: No, <30, >30.

I want a plot so that I can check what is the count of '<300' with '>30' i.e., how many patients had max_glu_serum = >300 and were readmitted in '>30' days

I tried the following code:

```
sns.catplot(y=train_data_wmis['max_glu_serum'], 
        hue=train_data_wmis['readmitted'], 
        kind="count", 
        palette="pastel", edgecolor=".6", dropna=True)
```

but it throws the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-384-1be2c9032203> in <module>
----> 1 sns.catplot(y=train_data_wmis['max_glu_serum'], hue=train_data_wmis['readmitted'], kind="count", palette="pastel", edgecolor=".6", dropna=True)

F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in catplot(x, y, hue, data, row, col, col_wrap, estimator, ci, n_boot, units, order, hue_order, row_order, col_order, kind, height, aspect, orient, color, palette, legend, legend_out, sharex, sharey, margin_titles, facet_kws, **kwargs)
   3750 
   3751     # Initialize the facets
-> 3752     g = FacetGrid(**facet_kws)
   3753 
   3754     # Draw the plot onto the facets

F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py in __init__(self, data, row, col, hue, col_wrap, sharex, sharey, height, aspect, palette, row_order, col_order, hue_order, hue_kws, dropna, legend_out, despine, margin_titles, xlim, ylim, subplot_kws, gridspec_kws, size)
    255         # Make a boolean mask that is True anywhere there is an NA
    256         # value in one of the faceting variables, but only if dropna is True
--> 257         none_na = np.zeros(len(data), np.bool)
    258         if dropna:
    259             row_na = none_na if row is None else data[row].isnull()

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Can someone help me, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a couple of things and finally found one solution to the above problem. Defined the following function:

```
def plot_stack(column_1, column_2):
 plot_stck=pd.crosstab(index=column_1, columns=column_2)
 plot_stck.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(8,8), stacked=True)
 return
```

Then,

```
plot_stack(train_data_wmis['max_glu_serum'], train_data_wmis['readmitted'])
```

Output:

[Stacked Plot of 'max_glu_serum' and 'readmitted'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWPby.png)

Please comment, if a better solution is available via Seaborn. Thanks